UnsupportedFeatureException: An object of type ...NestedFileSystemProvider was found in the image heap
I'm using graalvm-jdk-22.0.1+8.1 to build a spring-boot-starter native container image, but I get the following error:
[INFO]     [creator]     ================================================================================
[INFO]     [creator]     GraalVM Native Image: Generating 'com.example.demo.DemoApplication' (executable)...
[INFO]     [creator]     ================================================================================
[INFO]     [creator]     For detailed information and explanations on the build output, visit:
[INFO]     [creator]     https://github.com/oracle/graal/blob/master/docs/reference-manual/native-image/BuildOutput.md
[INFO]     [creator]     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]     [creator]     [1/8] Initializing...                                            (9.2s @ 0.13GB)
[INFO]     [creator]      Java version: 22.0.1+10, vendor version: Liberica-NIK-24.0.1-1
[INFO]     [creator]      Graal compiler: optimization level: 2, target machine: x86-64-v3
[INFO]     [creator]      C compiler: gcc (linux, x86_64, 11.4.0)
[INFO]     [creator]      Garbage collector: Serial GC (max heap size: 80% of RAM)
[INFO]     [creator]      2 user-specific feature(s):
[INFO]     [creator]      - com.oracle.svm.thirdparty.gson.GsonFeature
[INFO]     [creator]      - org.springframework.aot.nativex.feature.PreComputeFieldFeature
[INFO]     [creator]     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]     [creator]      2 experimental option(s) unlocked:
[INFO]     [creator]      - '-H:Name' (alternative API option(s): -o com.example.demo.DemoApplication; origin(s): command line)
[INFO]     [creator]      - '-H:+StaticExecutableWithDynamicLibC' (origin(s): command line)
[INFO]     [creator]     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]     [creator]     Build resources:
[INFO]     [creator]      - 8.83GB of memory (56.9% of 15.53GB system memory, determined at start)
[INFO]     [creator]      - 8 thread(s) (100.0% of 8 available processor(s), determined at start)
[INFO]     [creator]     SLF4J(W): No SLF4J providers were found.
[INFO]     [creator]     SLF4J(W): Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
[INFO]     [creator]     SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
[INFO]     [creator]     [2/8] Performing analysis...  []                                (51.5s @ 0.64GB)
[INFO]     [creator]         7,254 reachable types   (79.7% of    9,106 total)
[INFO]     [creator]         8,510 reachable fields  (48.4% of   17,574 total)
[INFO]     [creator]        30,520 reachable methods (51.2% of   59,658 total)
[INFO]     [creator]         2,514 types,   131 fields, and 1,782 methods registered for reflection
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     Error: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: An object of type 'org.springframework.boot.loader.nio.file.NestedFileSystemProvider' was found in the image heap. This type, however, is marked for initialization at image run time for the following reason: classes are initialized at run time by default.
[INFO]     [creator]     This is not allowed for correctness reasons: All objects that are stored in the image heap must be initialized at build time.
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     You now have two options to resolve this:
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     1) If it is intended that objects of type 'org.springframework.boot.loader.nio.file.NestedFileSystemProvider' are persisted in the image heap, add 
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]         '--initialize-at-build-time=org.springframework.boot.loader.nio.file.NestedFileSystemProvider'
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     to the native-image arguments. Note that initializing new types can store additional objects to the heap. It is advised to check the static fields of 'org.springframework.boot.loader.nio.file.NestedFileSystemProvider' to see if they are safe for build-time initialization,  and that they do not contain any sensitive data that should not become part of the image.
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     2) If these objects should not be stored in the image heap, you can use 
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]         '--trace-object-instantiation=org.springframework.boot.loader.nio.file.NestedFileSystemProvider'
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     to find classes that instantiate these objects. Once you found such a class, you can mark it explicitly for run time initialization with 
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]         '--initialize-at-run-time=<culprit>'
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     to prevent the instantiation of the object.
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     If you are seeing this message after upgrading to a new GraalVM release, this means that some objects ended up in the image heap without their type being marked with --initialize-at-build-time.
[INFO]     [creator]     To fix this, include '--initialize-at-build-time=org.springframework.boot.loader.nio.file.NestedFileSystemProvider' in your configuration. If the classes do not originate from your code, it is advised to update all library or framework dependencies to the latest version before addressing this error.
[INFO]     [creator]     
[INFO]     [creator]     The following detailed trace displays from which field in the code the object was reached.
[INFO]     [creator]     Object was reached by
[INFO]     [creator]       manually created constant
[INFO]     [creator]     --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]     [creator]         6.1s (9.6% of total time) in 130 GCs | Peak RSS: 1.21GB | CPU load: 6.54
[INFO]     [creator]     ================================================================================
[INFO]     [creator]     Failed generating 'com.example.demo.DemoApplication' after 1m 1s.
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to invoke layer creator
[INFO]     [creator]     unable to contribute native-image layer
[INFO]     [creator]     error running build
[INFO]     [creator]     exit status 1
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  04:41 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-05-14T13:34:10+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

I've also tried the --initialize-at-build-time suggestion without luck.
Steps to reproduce:

Go to https://start.spring.io/
Select: Maven, Java, Spring Boot 3.2.5, Jar packaging and Java 22.
Add the "GraalVM Native Support" dependency.
Download and unzip the project.
Run ./mvnw -Pnative -DskipTests spring-boot:build-image
The error above is displayed.

Any ideas on how to fix the issue and be able to build a native container image from the Spring Boot project with the provided options (Java 22, GraalVM JDK)?
Thanks in advance!

This is caused by a bug in the native image buildpack. As described in one of the comments, you can work around it with a little bit of additional configuration in your pom.xml:
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <image>
      <env>
        <BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS>-H:-AddAllFileSystemProviders</BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS>
      </env>
    </image>
  </configuration>
</plugin>


Thank you very much! I don't know how Google didn't return that result :)
It works for a simple Spring Boot project. Nevertheless I'm trying to use the Java Foreign Function and Memory APIs, which work when running "native:compile" but it seems to fail when generating the image with "spring-boot:build-image": UnsupportedFeatureError: Support for the Java Foreign Function and Memory API is not active: enable with -H:+ForeignAPISupport, even if -H:+ForeignAPISupport is already in the native-maven-plugin configuration in pom.xml

OK, disregard my previous comment. I understood I need to replicate the buildArgs configured for native-maven-plugin in the BP_NATIVE_IMAGE_BUILD_ARGUMENTS of spring-boot-maven-plugin

In my case the setting suggested by Andy Wilkinson did not work. Instead I had to add --initialize-at-build-time=org.springframework.boot.loader.nio.file.NestedFileSystemProvider to the build args of the Maven plugin for Native Image.
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.graalvm.nativeimage</groupId>
    <artifactId>native-image-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>native-image</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>package</phase>
        <execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <mainClass>my.MainClass</mainClass>
        <buildArgs>
            --verbose --no-fallback -march=native 
            --initialize-at-build-time=org.springframework.boot.loader.nio.file.NestedFileSystemProvider
        </buildArgs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Solution works with Spring Boot 3.3.3 and the Graal Native Image plugin org.graalvm.nativeimage:native-image-maven-plugin:21.2.0.
